# Linking taxonomy terms in views

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 8 and I am creating an internship placement system where students sign up and have a skills field (using taxonomy terms).

Employers can create job postings, which have same skills field.

How do I link matching fields (skills) in a view so that when a student logs in they only see jobs related to their skills?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use views as described below

### 1. Create a user view (not content view)

### 2. Add contextual filter user id with default value current logged in user

[image]

### 3. Add relationship on terms referenced from field skills (of user)

[image]

### 4. Add relationship with term from skills

[image]

**The previous relationship should be autoselected**

[image]

### 5. Now you can add content fields to view and the field skills relationship should be autoselected

[image]

when a user visits the view page the jobs will be contextually filtered based on their profile selections

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way that i could show the content instead of field in the Format>show area?

Comment: This was a user view so there is no content option (only user).  You can probably start with a content view and do the reverse relations and come to the same result (and be able to use content as SHOW option) but I still think `fields` is more flexible.